# Architecture of activity / fragments for search bar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a project in which on main screen I show a list of items . (An activity and a fragment that contains the list )
In title bar I want to add a search functionality with autocompletetextview . 
Now in title bar there are the title and "search" button . When the search will be clicked the title will be gone and autocomplete visible . 
I would like to follow the functionality that is now in common apps : messages , gmail etc but I can t figure what it is the best solution regarding architecture of fragments/activity components to implement .
1, When I clicks the search button to show another fragment ?
2. When I click search button , title change visibility to gone and it will be used the same fragment with items and it will be updated ?

Answer (score 0):

try with a simple [MVP](https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-2-model-view-presenter-8a6faaae14a5), organizing the view in a passive view(less data as possible). I have the feeling you are not practical of architecture if you ask, because looks as a simple question. MVP is in my personal opinion the best way to start.

you can test your app View using [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html), and the business logic into the presenter with [Junit](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html).

From the project indicated on the first link, you can easy clone the project and see an App that is quite similar to the one you use( on click opens a new activity, activities/fragment) plus much more.